# .Net Core 3.1 Angular Starter not serving static files on Linux

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, nginx

I'm trying to serve a .NET Core 3.1 Angular project from a virtual server at DigitalOcean.

First, I setup an Nginx server block for my subdomain democlient.mydomain.com and created a simple html file in /var/www/democlient.mydomain.com.
I then enabled SSL using Letsencrypt's certbot.
When I go to https://democlient.mydomain.com I see the contents of my html file.

I then created a new project using the .NET Core 3.1 Angular template on my Windows 10 PC.

```
dotnet new angular -o DemoClient
```

It runs locally on Windows 10. I git cloned it to my Ubuntu 18.04 machine at DigitalOcean, and made a symbolic link to the bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish folder in /var/www/democlient.mydomain.com.
I've built the app using

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release
```

and created a systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=.NET Web App - DemoClient

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/democlient.mydomain.com
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/democlient.mydomain.com/DemoClient.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=democlient
User=berten
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Debug
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Service status output:

```
● democlient.service - .NET Web App - DemoClient
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/democlient.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-04-03 09:47:03 UTC; 2h 40min ago
 Main PID: 3137 (dotnet)
    Tasks: 14 (limit: 1151)
   CGroup: /system.slice/democlient.service
           └─3137 /usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/democlient.muydomain.com/DemoClient.dll

Apr 03 09:47:04 leia democlient[3137]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Apr 03 09:47:04 leia democlient[3137]:       Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Apr 03 09:47:04 leia democlient[3137]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Apr 03 09:47:04 leia democlient[3137]:       Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Apr 03 09:47:04 leia democlient[3137]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Apr 03 09:47:04 leia democlient[3137]:       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Apr 03 09:47:04 leia democlient[3137]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Apr 03 09:47:04 leia democlient[3137]:       Hosting environment: Debug
Apr 03 09:47:04 leia democlient[3137]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Apr 03 09:47:04 leia democlient[3137]:       Content root path: /home/berten/repositories/DemoClient/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish
```

When I visit https://democlient.mydomain.com it shows "Loading..." but hangs there indefinitly. The browser console also says styles.css and runtime-es2015.js not found.
It seems my app is reachable but static files aren't loaded/served properly. I do have this in my Startup.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
if (!env.IsDevelopment())
{
     app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
}
```

My server block:

```
 listen 443 ssl;
 listen [::]:443 ssl;

 include snippets/ssl-democlient.mydomain.com.conf;
 index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

 server_name democlient.mydomain.com;
 location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

     proxy_pass              https://localhost:5001;
     proxy_http_version      1.1;
     proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
     proxy_set_header        Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }

 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/democlient.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/democlient.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

 server {
     if ($host = democlient.mydomain.com) {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 } # managed by Certbot
```

If I replace https://localhost:5001 with http://localhost:5000, I get redirected from democlient.mydomain.com to democlient.mydomain.com:5001.

I have no idea how I should proceed.